# C# Access to subclass Proprieties from base class instance

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I don't really know how to formulate my issue it's a bit complicated for me, i'll try my best to explain.

I'm making a space game, i have a base class which represent places, and i want to have different type of places like planets, space stations, asteroïds, trading ships etc. The player can click on those objects and get informations.

So my classes looks like something like this:

```
public class Place {

    public int placeId;
    public string placeName;
    public string placeDescription;

    /* Place constructor */

}

public class Planet : Place {

    /* Specific proprieties of planet */

    public PlanetType planetType;
    public int planetSize;
    ...

    // Planet constructor

    public Planet(int placeId, string placeName, string placeDescription,  PlanetType planetType, int planetSize) : base(placeId, placeName, placeDescription) {
       this.planetType = planetType;
       this.planetSize = planetSize;    
       ...
    }
}
```

And i have a delegate which accept a function like selectPlace with Place in parameters because i don't want to make a delegate for each type of Place i have.

In another script which is supposed to show the information of any kind of Place, i recieves the Place object that the player clicked on. I think i found a solution, however is this correct to do something like this ?

```
private void updateSelectedPlaceUI(object sender, EventsController.PlaceEventArgs placeArgs){
    // This is just a test, i should check which type of subclass it is before
    Planet planetTest = placeArgs.Place as Planet; // So now i can use planetTest.planetType
}
```

And placing this in a switch case so i can handle any type. I just want to be able to get the proprieties from any derived class of Place in order to display them in UI. I would like to know a better way to achieve this.

But i'm wondering if my design is ok and necessary, it has been a while since i haven't used inheritance / polymorphism, and i feel like i'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: If you know its always a Planet you can typecast it straight away (Planet)placeArgs.Place. If you don't, you should try to split up the event handles to correct types beforehand. If you cant do that you should see if you can add some typing in the base class instead, since as/is checking is not adviseable if not absolutely necessary.

Comment: You could override `ToString()`.

Comment: @Neijwiert I don't know the type so Planet was just an example here. Hmm yes i guess i could check types to send the correct one when the event is raised. Thanks.

Comment: "Visitor Pattern" anyone? Please don't switch or if-else subtypes of Place ... or even easier than VP: "tell, don't ask". Place can have a method "IEnumerable<string> getPlaceInfo()" - each subtaype will implement it accordingly. No need to cast.

Comment: @Fildor Ok i'll use a method in the base class then.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would propably make the UI part of showing the properties a specific place generic to accept something like a PropertyItem, you can decide the properties yourself.

```
public class PropertyItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your select method you would just call the abstract method of your base class (make your base class abstract as well)

```
public abstract class Place
{
    ... 

    public abstract IEnumerable<PropertyItem> GetProperties();
}
```

And now you can override this in your Planet

```
public class Planet : Place
{
    ... 

    public override IEnumerable<PropertyItem> GetProperties()
    {
        yield return new PropertyItem { Text = "Size", Value = this.planetSize };
    }
}
```

And eventually you would use the GetProperties() method to get the properties of your place and show them in a tabular or what ever format your UI knows how to handle the PropertyItem type.

```
private void updateSelectedPlaceUI(object sender, EventsController.PlaceEventArgs placeArgs)
{
    MyUserInterfaceWidget.DisplayProperties(placeArgs.Place.GetProperties());
}
```

Comment: Ok that's interesting. I'll have to try it, thank you.